# Need advice with OpenCV and RFID (Thesis)

Tags: java, c#, c++, opencv, rfid

My thesis's goal is to detect vehicles stopping at non permissible zones using a camera and issuing a violation to that particular vehicle by getting his vehicle identification and sending the data to a database. (Maybe through RFID)

I've gone through youtube and saw some 'zone' concept:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6gs10P2e1k

I've decided that:

- Violation Detecton: OpenCV
- Gathering Vehicle Identification: not sure if RFID(still researching for other options with the hope that there are easier ones)

**Question 1:** In the link above, he stated he used C++ for developing it. Is that kind of concept possible with c++ only? Can I apply those same concepts with Java, VB.NET, C#?

**Question 2:** For openCV, is the camera to be used up to me   or am I stuck with my laptop's webcam? Of course I need a clearer camera so there will be no 'camera constraints' for my program.

**Question 3:** Are there any technologies/techniques(better if easier) other than RFID to get some vehicle identification once a violator is detected?

**Question 4:** If I was going to use RFID, I need to manipulate RFID and OpenCV with their 1 common programming language to get them communicating (the condition of triggering the RFID to get the vehicle identification once there is a violation detected by the camera).

- OpenCV has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces and made possible to C# and       VB.NET through EmguCV.
- RFIDs can be manipulated using VB.NET, C, C++, C#, Java

Which do you recommend is the best 'common' language of the two that would suit my objectives?

**Question 4:** Do you think 6 months of average 2-3hrs per day of programming will be enough to finish this level of thesis project? I can't go all out on programming everyday because I still have other classes other than my thesis to attend to for the next 6 months.

Sorry, I know this a LONG question as a whole to answer so I'm asking for your kind patience to help me. :) Also you can answer minimum 1 of those 4 questions if you only know an answer to one of them.

Your help would much much much be appreciated! :)

UPDATE: 
I forgot to mention this is targeting public vehicles. I know private vehicles complain about having RFID for security reasons but public utility vehicles doesn't have a choice when the government enforces it. Here in the Philippines, the main concern of traffic are traffic obstruction caused by these public uitility vehicles who load/unload passengers anywhere they want w/o following the proper zones to do those things.

Comment: question 10: you go to your professor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is a library for image manipulation and can use images you send to it from any camera. You don't need to worry what camera you select.

Rfid is a radio technology which can be used for detecting "tags" as the pass by a scanner. There are numerous types of tags and detectors and they operate in different frequencies with different max distances. Usually it is quite short, up to 10 meters. There are secure standards but I suspect if you can place a tag on the vehicle at all, security is not the thesis main concern.

Rather than rdid, a technology that directly comes to mind for identifying vehicles is to take pictures of the license plate. Getting that to work reliably will take a lot of work though.

Any of these technologies can be addressed with either of the languages you ask about. Im a c# developer so that is my goto-language, but you should choose whatever you are more comfortable with and make sure the specific camera and rfid-scanner you choose have drivers for that language.

As for time; NO, with regards to how you put your question, I don't think you can

- select a camera hardware
- get images from it
- push the images through opencv to calculate if a vehicle has violated a zone
- select an rfid technology and hardware
- get tag information from it
- set up a database
- write transactions to the database

It is just a lot of moving parts and will take much more of work in reality, especiakky if you are not a seasoned developer.

Try to scope it all down is my advice.

Comment: We can place a tag on the public utility vehicles (See update). Yes I heard about that plate recognition and they said it requires a lot of work too and the main problem why I can't adopt it is because the camera is placed at a high place and not all the time can it see the plate number. Thank you for your answers!  I'm thinking of maybe going to a new topic instead. And, thank you for your patience in answering all those questions. God bless! :) When time is no longer an issue(when I graduate), I will go back and develop this topic